# how to organise a table with php and html?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I'm student so I'm beginner with code.

I made a search in a data base of MySQL, and the result was a table of 3 other tables:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      'type_de_sport' => string 'boxe' (length=4)
      'Adresse' => string '33 rue de Paradis' (length=17)
      'ville' => string 'Marseille' (length=9)
      'code_postal' => string '13006' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'type_de_sport' => string 'boxe' (length=4)
      'Adresse' => string '44 boulevard Sakakini' (length=21)
      'ville' => string 'Marseille' (length=9)
      'code_postal' => string '13005' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'type_de_sport' => string 'BOXE' (length=4)
      'Adresse' => string 'place a moi' (length=11)
      'ville' => string 'Marseille' (length=9)
      'code_postal' => string '13000' (length=5)
```

I would liked to organise this results and I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Type de sport</th>
      <th scope="col">Adresse </th>
      <th scope="col">Ville</th>
      <th scope="col">code postal</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <? for ($i=0; $i >$num ; $i++){ ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php $row=$i + 1 ; ?></th>
      <?php foreach ($resultats[$i] as $contenu) { ?>
      <td><?= $contenu ; ?></td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

please do you have anu other ideas?

Best regards

Comment: "didn't work" how, exactly? An error? Unexpected result? I can guess in this fairly straightforward case, but in general you should always give a clear and precise explanation of your problem when asking about issues with your code. It makes it much easier for people to help you. Otherwise they just have to start by asking _you_ questions instead.

Comment: what should your output look like and what did you get? Be specific on software versions. End of Review.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays. `$results` should contain the while array of arrays.

```
<tbody>

<?php 
   // $results is the main array
   foreach($results as $result){ 
   // so when we are looping here $result will contain one single array
   // this $result array is an associative array, so you have to access the values using the key
?>

    <tr>
       <td><?php echo($result['type_de_sport']); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo($result['Adresse']); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo($result['ville']); ?></td>
       <td><?php echo($result['code_postal']); ?></td>
    </tr>

<? } //end of foreach ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a handful of small logic problems in the code:

1. `$num` doesn't seem to be defined.
2. `>` should be `<`, because since you're incrementing `$i`, it'll either already be greater than `$num` (if it exists) and you'll get an infinite loop (and eventually a crash), or it won't be to begin with and the loop will never start.

You should be looping while `$i` is less than the size of the results array.

3. You never use `$row`, and it's not clear why you'd put that calculation inside a `<th>` rather than just in a code block. So I'm guessing you actually wanted to output that as a row number on the screen.

This will fix those little issues and the code should work nicely:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($resultats); $i++){ ?>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row"><?php echo $i + 1 ; ?></th>
      <?php foreach ($resultats[$i] as $contenu) { ?>
      <td><?= $contenu ; ?></td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6d214f826ec35e959d8420fcf3d95726557f3637